# Technology advice - Tablet based web application - (Platform independent) -Sort Of Enterprise Management System

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, drupal-7

I'm planning to develop a tablet based web application that is compatible on all platforms (iOS, Android, Blackberry etc). I need your advice in choosing the right technology.

Project Description: This web application should have the capability to generate user specific information, generate reports for high level managers (dynamic data) and ability to link with various systems belonging to multiple departments of an enterprise (say, HR & Manufacturing). Sort of a dashboard used for Content & User management.

Most importantly, ability to link with  previously build PHP applications and .Net applications.

Sample Scenario:

Lets say, a facility manager is in charge of 200 buildings, this application should be able to generate specific information for each levels across various buildings.

And normal residents on a level in a building, should be able to receive their specific information once they log in on to the system.

My Research:

- Drupal 7 offers great content management facilities, and some of its themes work on tablets and mobiles with ease. Only customization is required.

However, I doubt if we can link with our previously build .NET applications. This re

- jQuery Mobile & jQuery frame work has the framework for building the interface, but content management requires lot of coding.

My skill set: Intermediary skills in PHP & MySQL; Beginner in Drupal 7.

Is there a technology that can offer all of these like Content & user Management, inter connectivity with other applications, etc in one go with less coding & time.

I appreciate your efforts in giving me suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you keep it simple and use a web based interface i.e. plain old HTML/css and JavaScript.

All of the devices mentioned have full function web browsers supporting the latest HTML and CSS standards. You may need to tailor your css to cope with differing screen sizes.

It should be relatively each to develop a dynamic .NET based web front end to the existing applications.